# Custom Controls for iOS are always offset

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, drawrect

I'm making a few custom controls for iOS. Each of these controls draws various layers in drawRect and every single one of the layers seems to be offset for some reason. They're suppose to be centered in the view. Here's an example of a pie chart control:

```
override public func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)

    _valueLayers.forEach { (sublayer : CALayer) -> () in
        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    _valueLayers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let minDim = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
    let maxSliceWidthScale : CGFloat = self.sliceWidthScales.count > 0 ? min(self.sliceWidthScales.sort(>).first!, CGFloat(1)) : kDefaultSliceWidthScale
    let maxSliceWidth = maxSliceWidthScale * minDim * 0.5
    let center = rect.center()
    let sum : Float = self.values.reduce(0, combine: { $0.floatValue + $1.floatValue }).floatValue
    let maxRadius = (minDim - maxSliceWidth) * 0.5

    var currentStartAngle = self.startAngle

    for var x = 0; x < self.values.count; x++ {
        let ratio = self.values[x].floatValue / sum
        let angle = CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI * Double(ratio))
        let endAngle = currentStartAngle + angle
        let sliceWidthScale = self.sliceWidthScales.count > x ? self.sliceWidthScales[x] : kDefaultSliceWidthScale
        let sliceWidth = sliceWidthScale * minDim * 0.5

        var radius = maxRadius
        switch self.sliceAlignment {
        case .Inner:
            radius -= 0.5 * (maxSliceWidth - sliceWidth)
        case .Outer:
            radius += 0.5 * (maxSliceWidth - sliceWidth)
        case .Center:
            radius = maxRadius
        }

        let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        arcLayer.frame = self.layer.frame
        arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        arcLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: currentStartAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: self.clockwise).CGPath
        arcLayer.strokeColor = self.colors.count > x ? self.colors[x].CGColor : kDefaultSliceColor.CGColor
        arcLayer.lineWidth = sliceWidth

        _valueLayers.append(arcLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)

        currentStartAngle = endAngle
    }

    if self.showShadow {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = self.shadowColor.CGColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = self.shadowOpacity
        self.layer.shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset
        self.layer.shadowRadius = self.shadowRadius
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why these controls are offset in the frame. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line of code:

```
arcLayer.frame = self.layer.frame
```

When the layer's origin wasn't (0,0), the sublayer was being offset.